# Has there ever been a .NET flavored Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I've wondered this a bunch of times.  The answer that comes to mind is: there's no point since VS is so feature rich, but on the flip side, this the fact that something has already been done hasn't stopped people in the past.

Comment: There would be a point to a cross-platform IDE for those attempting to use .Net for cross-platform development with Mono. (This is not a recommendation for making that attempt.)

Answer (score 0):

There was a [C# plug-in for Eclipse](http://www.improve-technologies.com/alpha/esharp/) a long time ago, but it wasn't really production quality by a long shot. I haven't seen anything else coming into the Eclipse ecosystem to support .NET.

Answer (score 0):

[Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/) is a more recent plugin for C# on Eclipse. It's meant to work with either Mono or MS.NET.

Answer (score 0):

While not a whole C# environment, it's probably worth mentioning the Silverlight tools for Eclipse:

http://team.silverlight.net/announcement/eclipse-tools-for-silverlight-now-available/